# Multiple page sizes in iText7

Tags: itext7

I have developed a pdf using iText7 on my website to target US audience and set the default page size as letter for the printing:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(stream));
//To force the page to be 8.5*11 (default US format)
pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
```

However, the website is now bilingual for latin america and the default page size is not a good fit as they use A4 format. Therefore, even if the PDF looks greeat when they print, my footer is much higher and the left/right margins are much thiners.

Is there a way to adapt the page size automatically to fit most of the users in iText7?

Comment: You could offer the pdf in different page sizes on your web site.